# Como destacar a opção do menu referente a página atual?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá. Estou fazendo um site com abas, e gostaria de saber como faço para deixar a seção (palavra) do menu em destaque de acordo com a imagem.
Eu consegui colocar, porém ele só fica no menu **Início**, gostaria de quando estivesse na página **Sobre** o traço azul ficasse no menu *Sobre* e assim sucessivamente caso acessasse os outros itens do menu.
Desde já muito obrigado.

**Código HTML**

```
<div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:home' %}"  class="nav__link active">Início</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:sobre' %}"  class="nav__link">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:skills' %}"  class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:projetos' %}"  class="nav__link">Trabalho</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'blog:list' %}"  class="nav__link">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'contato:contato_email' %}"  class="nav__link">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

**Código JS**

```
$('.nav__link').click(function(){
    //remove class active
    $('.nav__link').removeClass('active');
    //adiciona class active ao item clicado
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Se vc vai tentar com JS uma alternativa que vc pode testar é pegar o window.location e aplicar a classe na opção com o href correspondente

Comment: Eu coloquei CSS também, mas só fica travado no inicio, ele não está dinâmico.
`.active::after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você removeu a classe active sem ter criado ela.Nesse trecho

```html
    
<div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:home' %}"  class="nav__link active">Início</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:sobre' %}"  class="nav__link">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:skills' %}"  class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:projetos' %}"  class="nav__link">Trabalho</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'blog:list' %}"  class="nav__link">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'contato:contato_email' %}"  class="nav__link">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Deveria ser assim,

```html
<div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item active"><a href="{% url 'pages:home' %}"  class="nav__link active">Início</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:sobre' %}"  class="nav__link">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:skills' %}"  class="nav__link">Skills</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'pages:projetos' %}"  class="nav__link">Trabalho</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'blog:list' %}"  class="nav__link">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="nav__item"><a href="{% url 'contato:contato_email' %}"  class="nav__link">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Então aplicava o JS, somente adcionei um trecho que vai identificar em qual página você ta navegando

```js
$('.item-menu').click(function(e) {
  $('.item-menu').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
//Aqui é onde ocorre a localização de que página o usuário se encontra.
const href = [location.pathname, location.search].join('?');
$('.item-menu[href="' + href + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Ele continua com erro no JS...

Comment: Oi, é que esqueci de mudar mas onde tem nav-item deveria ser item-menu.

Comment: Ele continua com esse erro de Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined